# Dependency activiti-spring-boot-starter not found

Tags: spring-boot, maven, activiti

I'm starting the spring-boot and the activiti dependency cant' download from this repo - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

**The error** - Could not find artifact org.activiti:activiti-spring-boot-starter:pom:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>[enter image description here][1]
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to have a more formatted pom.xml. And could you include the error that occurs.

Comment: hi, i'm edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that the version is not known:
`Could not find artifact org.activiti:activiti-spring-boot-starter:pom:unknown`.

You could specify a version like so:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
   <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>7.1.0.M6</version>
</dependency>
```

Which I found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic/6.0.0). However are you sure you have the right dependency? Looking at this [guide](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot) the dependency shown is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
  <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The difference being `activiti-spring-boot-starter` ->`spring-boot-starter-basic`

Comment: Thanks !! I'm changing it and it works!!